# In ruby rails, is there a method to get the objects outside of a where method's scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

For context, basically Im trying to find out which Users don't have a certain post, for example:

```
@specified = User.joins(:post).where(post: {content: "Goodbye!"})
```

vs. what I want to get (which is basically just every user that wasnt included)

```
!@specified
```

I tried negating it but it doesn't work apparantly, Is there a solution to this?

Comment: You can just add `.not`. Ex. `@specified = User.joins(:post).where.not(post: {content: "Goodbye!"})`

Comment: @crodev, I just tried it just now and apparantly it still doesnt get all users that I want, but I'm thinking it might be because those users dont even have any posts yet, so Im guessing .not doesn't cover null/nil?

Comment: An inner join only returns records that have an association. If you are interested in all records (users with certain kind of posts and users without any posts) you need an outer join. (the docs for [Joining Tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) cover both variants)

Answer (score 1):

This will give you duplicate users if user has more than one post and skip users without posts:

```rb
User.joins(:post) # should it be :posts?
```

You found what you don't want:

```rb
User.joins(:post).where(post: {content: "Goodbye!"})
```

`not` only filters out the post that has "Goodbye!", if a user has other posts, this user will be included in the result:

```rb
User.joins(:post).where.not(post: {content: "Goodbye!"})
```

Easy way out is to negate the whole thing:

```rb
User.where.not(
  id: User.joins(:post).where(post: {content: "Goodbye!"})
)
```